# Unable to passthrough JSON from API Gateway to SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sqs

API Gateway to SQS integration is not very well documented. The issue I have run into is that when POST'ing to an API Gateway REST endpoint that is set to passthrough json to SQS, I am receiving a 500 response. However when I test via the API Gateway console everything works fine.

The API Gateway logs show `Method request body before transformations: [Binary Data]` which leads me to believe that somehow the data is being ingested as binary instead of json for some reason.

Here is my Integration Request config:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue which was that in my swagger definition I included the following parameter which converts all requests to binary. Removing this param solved the problem for me:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types": [
    "*/*"
]
```

This can also be configured in the console under your API's settings within the "Binary Media Types" section.